# Trying to understand function prototypes

Tags: c

I'm going through K&R and I'm on the functions chapter, and I have a quick question:

Do I always have to declare functions as prototypes? What decides what kind of arguments will be in the prototype? Can it just be two variables in the function definition?

Thanks!

Comment: _You decide on basis of your requirement what arguments function should have_ . If your work is done with 2 arguments to function then pass two . Number of arguments are not predefined ( _built-in functions being exception_).

Comment: The prototype should be exactly the same as the function definition, followed by a `;`. Older versions of C permitted other ways to do this, but these can lead to confusion. If the function definition (execution body) appears in a module before it is actually called, there is no need for a prototype - because the compiler already knows about it.

Comment: No. You dont need to declare a prototype always. If you write several functions then writing prototype will help you to maintain the track. Lets say you need a function and you just typed a prototype and later you should complete that function. Otherwise you can write function as @Weather Vane described above.

Answer (score 1):

You should always declare *and define* your functions using prototype syntax; doing so allows the compiler to catch errors where you pass the wrong number or types of arguments in the function call.  C still supports declarations and definitions that don't use prototype syntax, but that's only to support ancient code bases; you should not write new code using the old syntax.

As for what arguments go into the prototype, that depends entirely on what the function needs to do.  Suppose I'm writing a replacement for the `pow()` function in the math library.  I need 2 arguments, one being the base and the next being the exponent:

```
double myPow( double base, int exp ); // declaration, prototype syntax
...
double myPow( double base, int exp ) // definition, prototype syntax
{
  ...
}
```

You can omit the parameter names in the declaration:

```
double myPow( double, int );
```

What matters is that the number and types of the arguments is specified.

The old-style declaration and definition would look like this:

```
double myPow( ); // declaration, old syntax
...
double myPow( base, exp ) // definition, old syntax
  double base;
  int exp;
{
  ...
}
```

The only time you don't choose the arguments for a function you're defining is the `main` function; while you get to define the implementation of `main`, you do not get to decide what arguments it will take.  `main` either takes no arguments:

```
int main( void )
```

or two arguments of type `int` and `char **`:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
```

An implementation *may* provide additional prototypes for `main` (such as a third `char **envp` argument found on some Unix implementations), but that's limited to the implementation - you are not allowed to create an arbitrary interface for `main`.